# Sum value pairs from array to get least difference between the pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say i have an array like so:

```
    var a = [
7.774,
7.877,
7.774,
7.868,
7.775,
7.861,
7.790,
7.850,
7.799,
7.848,
7.805,
7.842,
7.813,
7.835,
7.820,
7.833,
7.821,
7.829,
7.824,
7.825

]
```

now i want to pair them into an array half the size, where i sum 2 of the numbers together. I want to try to get the difference between the highest number, and the lowest number to be the smallest as possible.

So right now, i sort the array from smallest to largest. I then pair the first number with the last number, and continue until i meet in the middle.

So, with those numbers up there, i end up with:

```
var b = [
15.651,
15.642,
15.636,
15.640,
15.647,
15.647,
15.648,
15.653,
15.650,
15.649
]
```

Which then gives me a max difference of `0.017`. (`15.653 - 15.636`).

Is that the best that can be done?

this is the sort code (javascript):

```
a.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
for (var i = 0; i < (a.length / 2); i++) {
    if ((a.length-1) - i > i) {
        b.push(a[i]);
        b.push(a[(a.length-1) - i]);
    }
    else {
        b.push(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you've sorted them, you can just go through the list looking at every pair, keeping track of the smallest difference you've seen. I don't think there's any need for a second array.

Comment: If you're aiming for the smallest maximum difference, I think your current way is probably going to give you the best results

Comment: Yeah I am aiming  for the smallest maximum difference. Just want to make sure I am getting the best results since  it's pretty important for the purpose